# XML file does't load when HTML5 video plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html5-video

I should be able to loads the related XML file and displays the content of the XML file as the video plays back.

What am I missing?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/19/)

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
var XML_PATH = "http://www.adjustyourset.tv/interview/cuepoints.xml";

var cuepoints=new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadXML();
});

function loadXML()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: XML_PATH,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function onXMLloaded(xml) 
            {
                // set cuepoints
                cuepoints=$(xml).find("cuepoints");

                // loop for each cuepoint
                $(xml).find('cuepoint').each(function loopingItems(value)
                {   
                    // create an object
                    var obj={
                    timeStamp:$(this).find("timeStamp").text(),
                    desc:$(this).find("desc").text(),
                    thumbLink:$(this).find("thumbLink").text(),
                    price:$(this).find("price").text()};
                    cuepoints.push(obj);

                    $("#mycustomscroll").append('<ul>');
                    $("#mycustomscroll").append('<li id="item"><strong>'+(value+1)+"</strong><br/><strong>Time Stamp: </strong>"+obj.timeStamp+'</li>');
                });

                // close </ul>
                $("#mycustomscroll").append('</ul>');
                // append li tags
                $("#leftcolumn").append('<li src="'+cuepoints[0].desc+'"> <p src="'+cuepoints[0].thumbLink+'" /></li>');

                $("#price").append(cuepoints[0].price);

            }
    });
}
```

Comment: The functions are never called in the fiddle. Calling them manually during video playback works just fine on Chrome for me.

Comment: do you mind to fix the fiddle please?

Comment: @pimvdb   I've update the fiddle but still not working

Comment: @DD77: Who is calling init() ?

Comment: @karthick I gotcha, but the xml file doesn't load, I cant see the content. any help please?

Comment: @DD77: I am still not clear i am able to see the contents of the xml in firebug. Are you saying that you are not able to read the contents?

Comment: I'm not able to see the content displayed once load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Now i understood the question. You are able to get the xml from the ajax request but you are not able to parse it properly.

If you are concerned about this piece of code

```
  $(xml).find('cuepoint').each(function loopingItems(value)
                {    
            // create an object
                    var obj={timeStamp:$(this).find("timeStamp").text(), desc:$(this).find("desc").text(), thumbLink:$(this).find("thumbLink").text(), price:$(this).find("price").text()};
                    cuepoints.push(obj);

                    // append <ul> and timeStamp
                    $("#mycustomscroll").append('<ul>');
                    $("#mycustomscroll").append('<a><li id="item"><strong>'+(value+1)+"</strong><br/><strong>Time Stamp: </strong>"+obj.timeStamp+'</li></a>');
                });
```

then i suggest you to use `this.getAttribute('timeStamp') or $(this).attr('timeStamp')` 
instead of `$(this).find("timeStamp").text()` , you wont get anything from this because this is an attribute and not an element.

Comment: @DD77: And more over please avoid writing a find operation inside another find operation because they could lead to performance issues if you are handling with more data.

Comment: @DD77: No... I left the trying for you ^_^.

Comment: why I'm not able to see the others?
desc:$(this).attr("desc"),

thumbLink:$(this).attr("thumbLink"),

price:$(this).attr("price")};

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19491/discussion-between-karthick-and-dd77)

Comment: you are trying to use cuepoints[0].desc
Why are you doing this? it will return the xml not the object try using obj you created

Comment: @DD77: Glad to be of help. Accept the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is calling `init()`.

Change

```
function init() {
    // call loadXML function
    loadXML();
}
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadXML();
});
```